# Adding a PHP variable into the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't think it is possible to add a PHP variable into the .htaccess file. Unless I am wrong?

My website creates content from a data base. I would like to change the URL to match what is being show.

I want to change,

```
http://domain.com/products
```

to

```
http://domain.com/products/brand/partnumber
```

I have php variables for $Brand and $Partnumber

How do I change the URL based on what is being show?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "Change the URL" ?  Like, redirect the client to a new page?

Comment: For SEO I figured it would be better that each product had it's own URL. I have a database with all the product information. I dynamically create the product pages just trying to update the URL so that it would match what is being shown.

Answer (score 1):

Under products/index.php

```
<?php
 header("location: http://thisurl.com/products/".$brand."/".$partnumber);
?>
```

However, you may use a router, sth like http://github.com/klein/klein.php :

```
$klein->respond("/products/",function($request,$response){
   $response->redirect("/products/".$brand."/".$partnumber);
});
$klein->respond("/products/[:brand]/[:number]",function($request){
  return $request->brand." ".$request.number;
});

$klein->dispatch();
```

Comment: I have been trying your top example. I keep running into an infinite loop. But I think this is the direction I need to go.

Comment: @brendan: the under example is even much better as you can easy extend/implement it. Thazs how i did it with all my projects